# Отправка сообщений TDLib

Tags: c#, telegram, .net-core, tdlib

Разбираюсь с клиентом телеграм [`TDLib`](https://github.com/egramtel/tdsharp)
Застрял на банальной операции - отправка обычного текстового сообщения в канал.

вот мой метод отправки:

```
    var answ = await _client.SendMessageAsync
    (
        chatId: -1001443303410,
        options: new SendMessageOptions
        {
            DisableNotification = true
        },
        inputMessageContent: new InputMessageText
        {
            Text = new FormattedText
            {
                Text = "Formatted text to be sent; 1-GetOption(\"message_text_length_max\")"
            }
        }
    );
```

Проблема заключается в том, что после отправки я получаю ошибку `TdException: Chat not found`, хотя канал с таким ид создан и юзер отправляющий сообщение - админ

Comment: `chatId: -1001443303410,` - может этот айди динамический, и его значение нужно получить после прохождения аутентификации?

Comment: @Bulson насколько я понял - это ИД канала в который я шлю сообщение, по идее он не должен быть динамическим. Я когда отправляю команду `GetChatAsync(long chatId)` получаю инфо о канале без проблем и при разных сессиях он постоянный

Comment: Может нужно  сначала войти в канал, куда вы пытаетесь отправить сообщение?

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека сперва должна увидеть этот чат. Тогда получится в него отправить сообщение.
Увидеть чат она сможет, если в нем произошли какие-либо изменения. Или принудительно вызвать метод [getChats](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/getting-started#getting-the-lists-of-chats).